# Is there a way to visualize pickle files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pickle

I've created a pickle file through a python file:

```
with open("pets.pickle", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(animal, file)
```

And then wanted to open it in Visual Studio Code, but I got this message:
"The file is not displayed in the editor because it is either binary or uses an unsupported text encoding."

I was able to open it in Sublime Text though, and actually see the 0s and 1s, but I prefer to work with VS Code.
How can I make VS Code recognize a pickle file?

Thanks.

Comment: Pickle files aren't designed to be human-readable, what are you trying to do?

Comment: and you want to edit it too? Write an extension: `Pickle Viewer` that uses a webview to show a pickle file converted to json by a python script that you call as a system command. How should it handle the class constructions? All in all just write a simple pickle dump tool in python

Comment: Could you add the code snippet from vs code where you trying to deserialize the file??

Answer (score 4):

Pickles are serialized data. You cannot view them because they are binary representations. See the [data stream format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#data-stream-format) for the pickle module for more details.
If you have a step-debugger you can execute arbitrary python code in VSC, you're better off using the function [pickle.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load) inline.

Alternatively, you can create your own [extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api) in VSCode to interpret pickled objects within a debugger.

Comment: does that extension exist now?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension that I find helpful which you can download [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Percy.vscode-pydata-viewer). After installing the `vscode-pydata-viewer` extension, you can see the data inside a pickle file by just clicking on it. Please note that I save pickle files with the extension `.pkl` although you can use any extension for pickling in python.

To be clear I use a code like below to save to a pickle file:

```py
    with open('some_file.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: hi i have not any pickled file in my codes.but vscode shows same error: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.